# Character Themed Cryptic Clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

Another themed cryptic clues puzzle. This time the theme is simply "characters". The solutions will be characters, but they can be from anything, including but not limited to books, movies, TV shows, songs, operas, comic books etc.

Heard beam in space (3)

Container for selfless lookalike (6)

Two cans from Belgium (6)

He escapes quickly down the street? (10)

In racecar, mentor is stabbed (6)

Hint:

> The answer to clue number two comes from a famous piece of literature.

Comment: Is there an issue with the answer below at this point? Maybe it didn't get the check because no explanations?

Comment: @SendersReagent I upvoted because of the four correct answers. Number two is still incorrect. Will add a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about all of them but here are my guesses

Heard beam in space (3)

> Rey

Container for selfless lookalike (6)

> Carton (a great [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29826/character-themed-cryptic-clues/32752#32752)  given by Chris Cudmore)

Two cans from Belgium (6)

> Tintin

He escapes quickly down the street? (10)

> Roadrunner

In racecar, mentor is stabbed (6)

> Carmen

Comment: they're all correct except the second. I'd be interested to know how you got to it though. Tonight or tomorrow, I will add a hint, if it's not solved by then.

Comment: Number 2 could be: Zveebe, na rarzl bs Ongtvey

Comment: I'm not getting the "is stabbed" part of the last one.

Comment: In Act 4 of the opera Carmen is stabbed by José.

Comment: That explains it.  I fell asleep in the third act.

Comment: Got it! Nice one!

Answer (score 3):

Container for selfless lookalike (6)

> Carton - It is a far, far better thing that I do, than I have ever done

Comment: @hexonimo  Feel free to edit into your answer for completeness

Comment: Well done. I'm not sure if I would ever have gotten it. +1

Comment: Well, the Googles helped a lot.  But I started looking a Prince and The Pauper, Tale of Two Cities and other doppelganger works of fiction.

Comment: Nice one! I have to accept the main answer, but +1

Comment: @RichardRoe I would not expect otherwise.